# Method Digest on Main UI Thread

Tags: android, message-digest

I would like to compute the sha256 digest on a string.  Is it safe to compute the hash on the main ui thread?  Or do i have to run this in the background?

Comment: How long is the string?

Comment: @CommonsWare  The string is 12 chars.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely clear why you're hashing such a short string — the hash will be significantly larger than the input — but that should be very fast. You might run some tests to confirm that, but I expect that you can do that on the main application thread without issue.